# Error al intentar compilar la solución

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, estoy a días de tener que entregar mi proyecto y me sale este error, alguien que me pueda ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! decime que probaste reiniciando visual studio....

Comment: @NicoMelendez para aceptar la respuesta debes marcar el checkmark que sale al lado de mi respuesta, debajo de los botones de votación

Comment: @gbianchi, esta pregunta no necesita aclaraciones, este error no tiene nada q ver con codigo ni con teoria es solo un problema de Visual Studio

Comment: @Japv pero yo no le pedi codigo... y la solucion (si no funciona reiniciando) es lo que dijiste... igual, borrar las carpetas bin y obj es gratis.. no puede pasar nada malo, ya que no contienen nada que no se pueda recuperar recompilando....

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta correcta.. lee el [tour] que ahi te explica como...

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que antes de hacer lo que te voy a decir hagas una salva de tu proyecto en otro directorio para evitar males mayores.

A continuación te indico una posible solución a tu problema:

Debes cerrar el **Visual Studio**, y borrar las **carpetas bin** y **obj** de tu proyecto, después de hacer esto vuelve a abrir el **Visual Studio** y compila tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

algunas veces me paso eso lo que hice fue:
cerrar visual
copiar la carpeta de mi proyecto en el escritorio
Abrirlo en el visual desde el escritorio
Limpiar el proyecto
compilar y se solucionaba

El error que te dice es por tema de permisos suele suceder cuando trabajas con maquinas que tienen un dominio de una empresa o cuando el visual perdio privilegios en la carpeta del proyecto.

Otra opcion podria ser es ver si tu carpeta del proyecto tiene accesos de lectura y escritura o solo de lectura.

Espero te ayude Saludos.