# Error al cambiar struct por class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, consola, interpolacion

estaba siguiendo un tutorial y me encontré con el siguiente error:

Error       No se puede copiar "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe" en "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe". Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'obj\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe'.

Tenía el siguiente codigo:

```
namespace Tutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
            
            empleado.nombre = "John";
            Console.WriteLine($"El nombre es: {empleado.nombre}");
        }
    }

    struct Empleado
    {
        public string nombre;
    }
}
```

Y funcionaba bien, lo único que hice fue cambiar "struct" por "class" y entonces marcó el error, el problema parece estar en la línea

```
Console.WriteLine($"El nombre es: {empleado.nombre}");
```

Porque cuando la quito o la cambió por un formato del tipo:

```
Console.WriteLine("El nombre es: {0}", empleado.nombre);
```

El problema desaparece ¿algo que se me esté escapando sobre la interpolación de cadenas? Les agradezco mucho.

Comment: No es un problema de código es un problema con tus carpetas, posiblemente de permisos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495466/error-al-intentar-compilar-la-soluci%c3%b3n/495633#495633. Entra aki quizá te pueda servir

Comment: Múltiples respuestas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625239/unable-to-copy-a-file-from-obj-debug-to-bin-debug